# How to execute a procedure with DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, dbms-scheduler

I want to create a job that would drop a database object at a given date. The job created all right but the procedure is not executed. Tried executing the procedure alone and it works.

Here's the code for the create job

```
v_jobnam := v_objnam; 
                v_jobnam := DBMS_SCHEDULER.generate_job_name (v_jobnam);  

 v_startdate := to_timestamp(v_startdate); 
     select sysdate + (v_delhrs/1440) 
        into v_startdate
        from dual;

 DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(job_name => v_jobnam, job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK', JOB_ACTION => 'BEGIN DROP_OBJ1(' || v_objnam|| ', ' || v_objtyp || ', '|| v_schema || ',' || v_objid ||'); END;', start_date => SYSTIMESTAMP, repeat_interval => 'freq=secondly; bysecond=0', end_date => NULL, enabled => TRUE, comments => 'Calls PLSQL once');
```

where v_delhrs is a number.
 Here's the code for the procedure:

```
  PROCEDURE DROP_OBJ1
    (
        p_objnam       IN   CHAR,
        p_objtyp       IN   CHAR,
        p_copyto       IN   ALL_OBJECTS.OWNER%TYPE,
        p_objid        IN   NUMBER
    )
    IS

       v_objnam       VARCHAR2 (30);
       v_objtyp       VARCHAR2 (30);
       v_copyto       VARCHAR2 (30);
       v_objid        NUMBER (3);


    BEGIN

            v_objnam := UPPER (p_objnam);
            v_objtyp := UPPER (p_objtyp);
            v_copyto := UPPER (p_copyto);
            v_objid  := p_objid;
            --v_copyby := UPPER (p_copyby);

             EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ( ' DROP '
                               || v_objtyp
                               || ' '
                               || v_copyto
                               || '.'
                               || v_objnam
                               );

             EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ( ' DELETE FROM COPY_OBJ_DET WHERE OBJ_ID = '
                                || v_objid
                                );


         COMMIT;

    END;
```

I know its a very minor problem.
Thanks in advance gurus.

Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It apears to me that you have missed some quote marks in the DBMS_JOBS setup call.

Try this:

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(job_name        => v_jobnam,
                          job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
                          JOB_ACTION      => 'BEGIN DROP_OBJ1(''' || v_objnam 
                                             || ''', ''' || v_objtyp || ''', '''
                                             || v_schema || ''',' || v_objid 
                                             || '); END;',
                          start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP,
                          repeat_interval => 'freq=secondly; bysecond=0',
                          end_date        => NULL,
                          enabled         => TRUE,
                          comments        => 'Calls PLSQL once');
```

If this is not the solution I will setup your code on a database and try it myself.

Comment: Many thanks, it works.

In between, do you actually live on a sail boat?

Thanks, you made my day.
Cheers!

Comment: Yes - I sold my software company 2 years ago.  We have been up and down the east cost and to the Bahamas.  I live with my beautiful wife and 2 wonderful children on a 50 foot sailboat.

Comment: You could look into the user_scheduler_jobs view (or all_scheduler_jobs) to verify that your job's data is as you expected