# DBMS_SCHEDULER JOBS Running at morning until night everyday

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, jobs, job-scheduling, dbms-scheduler

I want make JOBS use DBMS_SCHEDULER in oracle 10g, where jobs refresh minutely with interval 2 minute running everyday start at 08.00 AM and end at 08.00 PM. I have tried this code,

```
BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB
    (
       job_name        => 'UPDATE_REKAP_BALI'
      ,start_date      => trunc(sysdate) + 8/24
      ,repeat_interval => 'freq=MINUTELY;interval=2'
      ,end_date        => trunc(sysdate) + 20/24
      ,job_class       => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS'
      ,job_type        => 'STORED_PROCEDURE'
      ,job_action      => 'UPDATEREKAPBALI'
      ,comments        => NULL
    );
END
```

but, when i check on the next day, the jobs is not running, i guess that the jobs is never running up again on 08.00 AM at the next day.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/scheduler-10g.php) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769906/how-to-execute-a-procedure-with-dbms-scheduler-create-job-procedure) as well, might be useful

Comment: If you end-date it then it will end, so you could maybe recreate the schedule every day. Or would it be feasible to run the procedure every two minutes all day, and have it check the time itself and just return if its outside your window? Neither sounds ideal though.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you commit after submitting the job.

**Edit** This is incorrect: DBMS_SCHEDULER performs an implicit commit, unlike the previous DBMS_JOB which required an explicit commit.

Comment: of course, i have tried others code, when end date i define it with null, and i check on the next day the jobs is still running,

Comment: As it was mentioned above, the end date parameter is when you want the job to completely stop and not run again: "This attribute specifies the date after which the job will expire and will no longer be executed. When end_date is reached, the job is disabled." So if you want it to run every day, then you want the end_date set to null. If you want the job to only run daily **between** 8 am and 8 pm, then you will have to express that in the repeat_interval parameter. See the Oracle documentation. Also, does your job complete within two minutes?

Comment: @Wolf DBMS_JOB requires a commit, but DBMS_SCHEDULER does not.  (I'm not sure why they designed it that way.)

Comment: @jonearles Well how about that, I spoke too soon and before double checking the documentation. I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make `auto_drop` to `false`  , because auto drop will make the job to be dropped once after it is running , so make it as false

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
    job_name        => 'TEST_J',
    job_type        => 'CHAIN',
    job_action      => 'TEST_C',
    auto_drop       => FALSE,
    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19;BYMINUTE=02,04,06,08,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58,00;BYSECOND=00;',
    enabled         => TRUE);

END;
/
```

Auto Drop is enabled by default 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm#i1000363

Answer (score 0):

The answer is two links far

1. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm#CIHGCDBJ - Table 93-54 Window Attribute Values
2. 'repeat_interval' line in the table point to "Calendaring Syntax" link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm#BABFBCEF where you can find out how to set a schedule in terms of Oracle

Comment: Please just to summarise content in links so your answer is still useful if the links go down in the future.

Comment: @Amicable in short Oracle DBMS Scheduler has a property 'repeat_interval' that is a string using what is called 'Calendaring Syntax'. You can see those syntax rules in Oracle Docs. I'd rather say the only place you should see those rules is the official Oracle Doc for the version of DBMS you use. <br/> I believe those links are quite fixed. But if they aren't you can find what you need by typing 'Oracle <number of DBMS version> Calendaring Syntax' in web search