# DBMS scheduler oracle - how to execute a procedure

Tags: oracle, scheduler

I'm loosing my mind. I have a procedure named foo() which takes no arguments. I'd like to execute it, let's say, every 3 minutes. The code I wrote looks like:

```
BEGIN
    dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name => FooJob,
                                  job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
                                  job_action => '
                                                 BEGIN 
                                                  foo();
                                                  END;',
                                  start_date => SYSTIMESTAMP,
                                  repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=3;BYHOUR=17;BYMINUTE=35;',
                                  enabled => TRUE
                                  comments => 'A comment.');
END;
/
```

This gives me an error: identificator 'applyjobpenalities' should be defined.

I based on this example: [How to execute a procedure with DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769906/how-to-execute-a-procedure-with-dbms-scheduler-create-job-procedure)

Also:

1) How to execute `dbms_output.put_line()` after execution of foo();? Is it possible to just put this line strightly away?

2) How to check if procedure `foo()` is (was) executing on behalf of scheduler?

**UPDATE:**
Ok so what I've done is:

1) I typed in SQL Plus 'set serveroutput on'

2) I made a procedure:

```
create or replace procedure proc1
IS
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line('sth');
end;
/
```

3) I changed scheduler code to:

```
BEGIN
dbms_scheduler.create_job(  job_name    => 'JustATest',
                                job_type    => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
                                job_action  => 
                                                    'BEGIN 
                                                    proc1();
                                                    END;',
                                start_date  => systimestamp + interval '10' second,
                                repeat_interval => 'FREQ=SECONDLY',
                                enabled     => TRUE);
END;
/
```

But I can't see any result in SQL Plus. What am I missing? Both procedures compiled succesfully and I can see this job when I type:

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS;
```

Comment: Read the docs - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedadmin002.htm#ADMIN12039  Please show the complete error stack trace.  you cannot "see" dbms_output from a background job.

Comment: proc1 is running in the background.  You cannot see the output from dbms_output.  Not sure how to make that any clearer.  Write to a log table if needed.

Comment: I understand now, thanks. But if I use other procedure which updates data I don't see it actually running. What's wrong then?

Answer (score 2):

1) There is no way to extract DBMS_OUTPUT from a scheduled job.

2) To check if FOO was executing, I use the following SQL (extracted from TOAD's "Spool SQL to Screen" option. If you are going to be spending any time at all developing in Oracle, get TOAD for Oracle).

```
  SELECT l.job_name
  , l.JOB_SUBNAME
       , l.log_id "Log ID"
       , l.log_date "Log Date"
       , l.operation "Operation"
       , l.status "Status"
       , l.user_name "User Name"
       , l.client_id "Client ID"
       , l.global_uid "Global UID"
       , r.req_start_date "Required Start Date"
       , r.actual_start_date "Actual Start Date"
       , r.run_duration "Run Duration"
       , r.instance_id "Instance ID"
       , r.session_id "Session ID"
       , r.slave_pid "Slave PID"
       , TO_CHAR (r.cpu_used) "CPU Used"
       , r.additional_info "Additional Info (Run)"
    FROM dba_scheduler_job_log l, dba_scheduler_job_run_details r
   WHERE l.log_id = r.log_id(+)
   and l.job_name like 'FooJob'
ORDER BY 1 DESC NULLS LAST;
```

2b) To see jobs that are currently running:

```
 SELECT *
  FROM dba_scheduler_running_jobs;
```

3) If you want to see results from your job, you need to have your job do something, such as insert a record into a table.

Comment: So it is impossible to see notifications from an executed procedure as I posted above in the edit section?

Comment: Yes, it is impossible.  Write to a table if needed.

Comment: Fine. I changed this procedure with procedure which does bunch of select/updates operations and now when I execute this and type select from 2b) of your post I see as a result 'No rows where selected'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It may be that the job ran and finished. It may also be that the job scheduler is not running. To see if jobs are queued up, execute "select * from SYS.DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS". To see a history of jobs, execute "SELECT *
  FROM SYS.DBA_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG". If these have been queued as the person who is logged in, substitute 'USER' for 'DBA'.

Answer (score 0):

Change `Job_action => 'proc1';`

And in another notepad type

```
    BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB(
    JOB_NAME            => 'justATest',
    USE_CURRENT_SESSION => FALSE);
    END;
```

And then execute the above code

Answer (score 0):

You can see result of dbms_output.put_line() in dba_scheduler_job_run_details column "output".
Put in job action

```
BEGIN 
  foo();
  dbms_output.put_line( 'foo executed in job' ) ;
END;
```